# Cross Platform Browser Detection

Tags: c++, firefox, browser, cross-platform, wxwidgets

Can anyone help me out, I need a cross platform way to detect if browsers are installed e.g. Is Firefox installed, Is Safari installed etc.
I am using wxWidgets for my GUI libary if this helps.

I can check the registry on windows but am unsure on how find out browsers for Linux and Mac. Would prefer one clean cross platform way rather than several 
If(windows)
then search registry

If (Mac)
then do something else
etc.

Thanks

Comment: Many modern *nix define a "browser" environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6.3/wx_miscellany.html#wxlaunchdefaultbrowser?

And why not using several ways of detection? This functionality could then be implemented in wxWidgets itself. After all, wxWidgets does exactly this and just abstracts it away using function with platform specifics hidden behind.

Comment: I belive that wxlaunchdefaultbrowser only launches the browser and does not report on if browser X is installed.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you only want to open *any* browser to show a URI, use that one. If you want to open a special browser, you have to do the checks yourself. But then again, I don't know what you want to achieve… but beware that there are people who only have rekonq installed. So always give your users the possibility to add own browsers at will.

Comment: Yes, it the those "checks" that I am looking to do in a cross platform clean way. I am trying to do simular to what Dreamweaver CS5 does with its File->Preview in Browser and it gives a list of browsers that the user has installed, not just using the users default browser. Though it is not done perfectly in Dreamweaver it doesnt seem to detect that I have safari installe.d

Comment: So simply allow the user to configure your program. The user enters a name (rekonq) and selects a file using an open file dialogue (/usr/bin/rekonq). This way a user is completely free. He even can install various different versions of any browser and have them all in his list. Similar to Firefox for Unix "find installed plugins", you can add some kind of wizard which does a `which <name>` and lists them all. You maintain that list `[ "firefox", "rekonq", "konqueror", "lynx" ]`. The user just need to pick any found item to fill his list.

Comment: It is a good idea to allow the user to add there own additional browsers, but I would like to be able to detect popular browsers and pre-populate the list, saving my users some time.